# Complex regex pattern for science

Tags: c#, regex

For a project I'm working on, we need to analyse, calculate and process data with R. To do some accurate calculations, our scientists would like to have a regex expression that match the following on our input.

```
12
1.12
1.00021
234.0012
23.020
123.012
123.0000000000012
1.0000000000023
```

As you can see the decimal places of the values can have any number of zeros but it's only valid if the zeros are followed by a number between `10` and `99` (inclusive).

So the following should **not** be valid.

```
1
0.0001
0.02
8.000000001
1.01
```

Hope someone has a solution or a direction, because I'm quite stuck.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing how the first set of exmaples differs from the second. What **rules** determine if a number is *valid*?

Comment: It's really good to show your progress ... anyway you can try something like this [1-9]d+(.d+)?

Comment: @ssimeonov that would capture any number with a decimal point.

Comment: I missed the 10-99 requirement. So it would be [1-9]d(.d+)?

Comment: So `23.020` is *valid*, but `23.02` would *not* be valid, right? So basically split by decimal separator, turn right part into an integer (ignore leading zeros) and see if that integer is between `10` and `99`, right? -- so `23.0111` would also be *invalid*.

Comment: Yes but dont gorget to check if there is no decimal part the int part should be >10 as 12 is valid and 1 is not

Comment: @Corak `23.020` is one of the **valid** examples it seems.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer - exactly. But from what I understand, OP sees a *difference* between (the strings) `"23.020"` and `"23.02"`. I'm asking for clarification on exactly that point.

Comment: @Corak Ah, sorry I misread that.

Comment: The point that trips me up is *"it's only valid if there is are a minimum of (scope of zeros) 10 - 99 as decimals"* and then there are several examples that obviously do **not** satisfy that condition (`1.00021`, `234.0012`, etc.).

Comment: Oooh wait, I think I get it.

Comment: @Corak, 23.030 is valid, 23.03 is not valid...
23.0000003 is also not valid

Comment: I had someting like ^(\d{1,}(\.\d{1,2})) but it's not even close...

Comment: @BryanvanRijn - Okay, because you see `"23.030"`, take the decimal part `"030"` and then say, that `30` is between `10` and `99`, so it's *valid*. While with `"23.03"` you take the decimal part `"03"` and say `3` is *not* between `10` and `99`, so that is *in*valid. I think I understood that. -- But then, why is `1` by itself *invalid*, while `12` by itself is *valid*? Is the logic: "if there is **no** decimal part, then *the number itself* must be between `10` and `99`"?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, decimal places can have **any** number of zeros followed by `10`-`99`, right?

```
\d+(\.0*[1-9][0-9])
```

What I don't see is how you make a distinction between `12` being valid and `1` not.

Comment: That's a winner!  Wow, you regex guys are great! :)

Comment: @BryanvanRijn A couple of notes to that solution: I've forgot a slash before the dot in my initial solution, effectively making it a wildcard (would have matched `10x0023` too), and it does not account for pure integers (without a decimal point).

Comment: Also, in some cultures, the decimal separator is a comma (`"10,23"`), but that might not be relevant here.

Comment: This would be another possible solution to account for the integer part, not enough data to confirm however: [Example on Regex Storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5cd%2b%28%5c.0*%5b1-9%5d%5b0-9%5d%29%29%7c%28%5b1-9%5d%5b0-9%5d%29&i=Valid%3a%0d%0a12%0d%0a1.12%0d%0a1.00021%0d%0a234.0012%0d%0a23.020%0d%0a123.012%0d%0a123.0000000000012%0d%0a1.0000000000023%0d%0a%0d%0aInvalid%3a%0d%0a1%0d%0a0.0001%0d%0a0.02%0d%0a8.000000001%0d%0a1.01&o=m)